# Should we capitalize titles in questions?

Tags: discussion, question-titles

Some titles are capitalized, some are not. According to [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14/17427) there are several styles.

Should we pick one or just follow the mood?

Comment: I think you mean eg. But I get what you're saying.

Comment: -1.  Nothing personal, just not really worth thinking about

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me like we have two main ways that people title their questions.

- **As a stand-alone question:** This is the type of question with a title of the format "Why is xyz true according to abc?" The distinguishing feature of this type of title is a question mark at the end. I think that these should be capitalized according to proper English *sentence* capitalization rules.
- **As a summary of the topic of the question:** An example of this would be msh210's question *[Omissions with tachanun in nusach Ari](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29496/omissions-with-tachanun-in-nusach-ari)*. This type of question is not a complete English sentence, and I think it should be capitalized according to the rules (whichever particular guideline the OP cares to use) for titles.

I don't think that the capitalization rules of questions are particularly important for us, though, and I don't know that we have to edit questions just to fix capitalization. I don't even think I really follow these guidlines myself. There might be times, though, where we would want to edit a question title to fix capitalization. Examples include if the OP leaves the word "I" or a proper noun uncapitalized. Maybe a good rule would be, if the capitalization scheme of a title feels "jarring", fix it. Otherwise, leave it.

**Summary**

I don't think there's anything wrong with having guidelines, but it's probably not worth our time to enforce them strictly.